# Monogame Xamarin android catch Back hardware key

Tags: c#, android, input, xamarin, monogame

I'm trying to catch the back keypress (hardware) so I can prevent it exists my game but shows the game menu.

I tried overriding the OnBackPressed in my AndroidGameActivity but it doesn't trigger when pressing back. My game exists :(.

So I digged a bit deeper and saw that the on the Window member of the Game object you can use SetOnKeyListener. 
I'm now having a OnKey method in my listener class which get triggered at a keypress.
That is nice to react on keypresses but it still exits my app because it didn't really override it, it is only a listener. 
It still goes in the the AndroidGameActivity OnKeyDown and checks if its "Back" and then exits the app.

I saw that [https://github.com/dineshkummarc/MonoGame-2.5.1.0-0/blob/master/MonoGame.Framework/Android/AndroidGameWindow.cs
already has a OnKeyDown override. You can see there it exits the app if back is pressed.

So how can I prevent it from exiting when clicken the back hardware key?
Should I override OnDestroy and check the gamestate ?

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Back button will exit your game automatically. Double check that you aren't manually exiting in your Game::Update method. A lot of XNA tutorial out there has that code, so it's possible it sneaked in without you noticing.

Look for something like this:

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    // Allows the game to exit
    if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == 
        ButtonState.Pressed)
        this.Exit();
```